# Where can I get great documentation about Exception handling in C#

Tags: visual-studio-2008, exception, c#-3.0

I'm searching for a good website or a books that give great example of Exception Handling in C# 2008 such as SQL exception management and all the other. I'm programming in 3 tiers.

I'm already doing it well in VB .Net 2008 and I'm now moving foward to C#. The transition isn't hard, but I need a bit more information about exception handling in C# that is quite different from VB behaviours.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try looking at the [MSDN Exception Handling Applicaton Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309505.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it worth the check. Looks like to be very powerfull but maybe a bit overkill for my needs, but I put it in my fav so when I'll have the time, I'll check it back. Thx!

Comment: You can look at the source code to gain a better understanding then create an application block that fits your needs.  That is what we did at my current job.

Comment: Also, give an upvote for any answer you find helpful for resolving your problem or answering your question.

Comment: Yes true. The only problem is that I have some delay to respect and I can't realy waste a week on that whether I know it WORTH it... but I have delay to respect so... :(

Comment: Concerning vote up, I can't it always tell me that I need "15 repuration" to do it...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the official docs at MSDN to be the best resource on core language features. Specifically, see this page and the pages it links to: [Exceptions and Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(loband).aspx)

Comment: Already seen before, but always a good place to start and come back sometime for a refreshing ;)

Answer (score 1):

I taught a C# class using the book below.  The information on handling exceptions from a functional perspective is OK.  At the "Best Practices" level was not the best.

[http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-21-Days/dp/0672320711](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672320711)

Comment: Actually I already have a good base in C#, I only want to do a well done exception manager in my future application that'll be in C#. That's why I'm searching some docs on how to achieve a good system of exception handling to avoid user dealing with weirdo message and also help me to diagnose problem faster with the help of the thrown exception. Whatever, thanks you for your time!